# open ports but shut down services

Tags: networking

Of course I realise not to do this under normal circumstances, but theoretically when you have open ports on your outside IP address (i.e. let say port 443) and issue the command "sudo service apache2 stop".  Now Apache is no longer running and my web server is down.  Port 443 is  vulnerable right?  Theoretically how would an attacker get into my machine and have a look around?

The question is purely academic interest.

Comment: The port is still open, but if nothing is listening on the port, I don't see how it could be vulnerable, unless there was a fundamental flaw in how the operation system handled the TCP connection, but in that case the issue would be still there even if Apache was listening on the port.

Answer (score 1):

I take it the port is open in the firewall, but there is nothing listening on it.

A modern OS that hasn't been attacked is not vulnerable because it will just filter out this traffic.

If OS however was targeted with deliberately crafted malware, it is possible to read incoming traffic on the port, in fact, on any ports. Pretty much everything is possible in the kernel if you have sufficient skills.

Comment: And yes open port on the firewall (router) but no services.  Frequently I do figure things out in my Apache2 environment because I do not know everything.  Not yet at least.  ;)  Anyway I might shut the service down while I am figuring stuff out and forget to turn off my ports forwarding to my server.  I often wondered who broke in while Apache2 was down.  Obviously I can look at the network log in /var but every time I do that I have to filter out all the thousands of failed attempts.  I see this and know I am right about using private key authentication.  BTW the OS is Ubuntu.